# How does vim color scheme work for different file types?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm new to vim. I want to customize my vim look nice. I find some very nice looking color schemes by google. But I'm wondering how these color scheme work when I open different type of files. I work mainly with javascript. So if I pick SOLARIZED color scheme for example, when I open html or js files, will the color scheme highlight javascript or html syntax differently?

if yes, does that mean a color scheme always contains a complete set of syntax highlighting solution for all kinds of file types?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about customizing text editor. Consider corresponding [VI.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) site or http://superuser.com.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov By your logic, about 50% of vi/vim questions are off-topic on stackoverflow.  I'm not saying it's a good question.

Comment: @EvergreenTree I'd say 90% should be asked on VI. This META discussion covers which one could be asked on both SO/VI and which should be now on asked on VI - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089/is-it-appropriate-to-post-vim-questions-on-stack-overflow-now-that-there-is-a-vi

Comment: ok, I didn't know there's a vim site, can I move my question to that site?

Answer (score 2):

Most *filetypes* (like `python`) in Vim come with a syntax that defines highlight groups (see them via `:highlight`). These particular groups (e.g. `pythonFunction`) are then *linked* to a set of default groups (`:help highlight-groups`, e.g. `Identifier`). A *colorscheme* then provides combinations of foreground / background color and/or formatting like bold and italic (separately for terminals, color terminals, and/or GVIM) for the default groups.

highlight group → default group → color + style
`pythonFunction` → `Identifier` → `term=underline ctermfg=3 guifg=DarkCyan`

So, for a set of beautifully matching colors that please your personal taste, you choose a colorscheme. In order to tweak some particular associations, you can change the linking of highlight group to default group, e.g.:

```
:hi link pythonFunction Special
```